# WordPress lightbox categories in ACF Gallery?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, lightbox, advanced-custom-fields

I currently have this piece of code, which gets all the images added to a gallery in the CMS, and displays them all. Once displayed, they can be cycled through in a lightbox.

```
<div class="container-fluid gallerysector">
    <a id="gallery"></a>
     <div class="container gallerysectorcontent">
      <?php 
            $images = get_field('gallery', options);
                if( $images ): ?>
                <div class="row" style="padding:60px;">
                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" rel="lightbox[3|filename]">
                                                <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"  />
                                            </a>
                                            <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                                        </div>

                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My issue is as follows.

I need to be able to have categories. For example instead of having 20 images in a gallery, which are displayed on the site. Have 4 categories displayed on the page, and when they are clicked, you can loop through the images in that gallery?

Thanks in Advance!
See comments too!

Comment: Or basically, at the minute this loop is getting EVERY image and adding a lightbox. IS there a way to display only the FIRST image but still get the other images inside the lightbox?

Comment: Anyone got the slightest idea?